# How do I do this without checking the return value?

Tags: c#

I want to make a function that reads the console for a key, check it's validity and then return.

This is my solution but it doesn't work, why?

```
public static int KeySupplier()
{
    string keyString;

    Console.WriteLine("Please provide a valid cipher key");

    keyString = Console.ReadLine();
    if(int.TryParse(keyString, out int key) == true)
    {
        return key;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid key!");
        KeySupplier();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not wrk" means 'does not compile because of error "not all paths return a value"'? Pretty obvious, isn´t it? If your method gets to the `else`-branch, your method has no return-value. You should use `return KeySupplier()` here.

Comment: oh didn't know I could do that.. Many thanks

Comment: Plain loop until valid key is parsed would be much more clear (readable and expected) here than recursion.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `== true` is not necessary.

Comment: Close voters: "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem" The code in this question **absolutely reproduces the problem** (it won't compile!) and is about as short as it can be without losing the context of *what the OP is trying to achieve*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this code to compile, all paths where the function exits **must** return an `int`. The simplest way to solve this is to change your code so that it reads:

```
public static int KeySupplier()
{
    string keyString;

    Console.WriteLine("Please provide a valid cipher key");

    keyString = Console.ReadLine();

    if(int.TryParse(keyString, out int key) == true)
    {
        return key;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid key!");
        return KeySupplier(); // 'return' added here
    }
}
```

That said, what you've written is perhaps not the best way to solve the problem as you may encounter a [`StackOverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=netframework-4.8). If someone who was running this code was to simply keep pressing a non-numerical letter you'd end up in many, many nested calls to `KeySupplier` which could eventually throw an exception.

Another way to implement this, assuming that the intent of the code is to simply return any string that parses as an `int` would be to use a `while` loop:

```
public static int KeySupplier()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please provide a valid cipher key");
        var keyString = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(keyString, out int key))
        {
            return key;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid key!");
    }
}
```

When this method is called, it sits in the `while` loop until a string that can be parsed as an `int` is entered by the user, at which point the method returns it to the calling code.

Comment: And what if you want to cancel out?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, that's not listed as a requirement; nor is it implemented in the OPs  (non-compiling) code. Adding it in would only serve to over-complicate the example. A *simple* solution would be to `Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL-C to exit");` but perhaps neater would be to add an instruction to type QUIT and add a check for that being the content of `keyString`. But.... then you'd get into the realms of changing the return type of the method to facilitate indicating that the user had cancelled out (`int?` perhaps) or picking a magic number to indicate it...

Comment: ... adding it is one thing, adding it *right* is quite another and would potentially mask the gist of the answer =)